# Good Jquery Autocomplete plugin consuming JSON 

Tags: jquery, json, autocomplete

I have my customers name in json format i have to use it in a textbox such that it auto completes to give list of users ...  Any good Jquery Autocomplete plugin consuming JSON..

I have gone through a similar question of stackoverflow but it didnt help me

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188442/whats-a-good-ajax-autocomplete-plugin-for-jquery

Comment: Your previous question being more than 15 months ago, I'd agree that this isn't a duplicate; things have hopefully moved on.

Comment: It would be good, though, if you could list the ones you've found that you aren't happy with.

Comment: And a sample of your JSON to give an idea of format. Or is this flexible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

> - [Efficient AutoSuggest with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2443362/efficient-autosuggest-with-jquery)
> - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256105/what-is-the-best-jquery-autocomplete-suggest