# Efficient AutoSuggest with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, time, autosuggest

I'm working to build a jQuery AutoSuggest plugin, inspired by Apple's spotlight.

Here is the general code:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
$('#q').bind('keyup', function() {

    if( $(this).val().length == 0) {
        // Hide the q-suggestions box
        $('#q-suggestions').fadeOut();
    } else {
        // Show the AJAX Spinner
        $("#q").css("background-image","url(/images/ajax-loader.gif)");

        $.ajax({
            url: '/search/spotlight/',
            data: {"q": $(this).val()},
            success: function(data) {
                $('#q-suggestions').fadeIn(); // Show the q-suggestions box
                $('#q-suggestions').html(data); // Fill the q-suggestions box

                // Hide the AJAX Spinner
                $("#q").css("background-image","url(/images/icon-search.gif)");

            }
        });
    }
});
```

The issue I want to solve well & elegantly, is not killing the sever. Right now the code above hits the server every time you type a key and does not wait for you to essentially finish typing. What's the best way to solve this?
A. Kill previous AJAX request?
B. Some type of AJAX caching?
C. Adding some type of delay to only submit .AJAX() when the person has stopped typing for 300ms or so?

Comment: Have you looked at the new autocomplete plugin from jQuery UI http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/?

Comment: @nobosh: i am after implementing efficient autosuggest without killing server and if you able to come-up with something you think its efficient would you share the sample server side code? - thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try using [Ben Alman's Throttle & Debounce plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/)

Lets you "delay" things till the user is done.

For an example on how to use it check out his [example of debouncing with a pretend autocomplete](http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce/examples/debounce/)

Your code would basically become

```
var qinput = $('#q').bind('keyup', $.debounce( 250, function() {

    if( $(this).val().length == 0) {
        // Hide the q-suggestions box
        $('#q-suggestions').fadeOut();
    } else {
        // Show the AJAX Spinner
        qinput.addClass('loading');

        $.ajax({
            url: '/search/spotlight/',
            data: {"q": $(this).val()},
            success: function(data) {
                $('#q-suggestions')
                    .fadeIn() // Show the q-suggestions box
                    .html(data); // Fill the q-suggestions box

                // Hide the AJAX Spinner
               qinput.removeClass('loading').addClass('search');
            }
        });
    }
}));
```

CSS

```
.loading{
    background: url('/images/ajax-loader.gif');
}
.search{
    background: url('/images/icon-search.gif');
}
```

You will note that I removed your background-image css and replaced them with addClass/removeClass.  Much easier to manage css stuff in css files.

Comment: Sounds interesting, but that's a lot of code for this don't you think?

Comment: Wouldn't call 0.7kb a lot of code http://github.com/cowboy/jquery-throttle-debounce/raw/v1.1/jquery.ba-throttle-debounce.min.js

Comment: True. How would you suggest implementing Throttle on the code above? I'm not seeing how to utilize the plug-in in this regard. thxs

Comment: Updated the answer with a link to his example of a pretend autocomplete widget using debounce and an example of your code using debounce.

Answer (score 2):

I'd go for a variant of C. Don't wait for users to stop typing, but wait some time (200ms?) after the first keystroke. Then after that time, you will in many cases have received additional keystrokes and then you use the typed characters to get the autosuggest. If another key is pressed after submitting the request, you start counting again.

And you should definitely do some caching too; people will use backspace and you'll have to show the name list again.

Comment: Thxs, can you offer some tips on how to implement a Delay & Caching?

Comment: You might want to look at the jQuery plugin here: http://code.google.com/p/jquery-autocomplete/
It supports parameters like delay and cacheLength

Answer (score 2):

I don't know, what DB are you using OR are you using hardcoded file!?

anyway a good starting point is wait for a least a **TOT NUMS** of chars for

es.: after 3 ( that is a min word lenght for search mysql in most cases ) chars 
then you can start to search your DB or json file!

I think you must give to PHP or others the hard job like **FILTERING** etc, etc.. 
before send back the responce!

btw i think one of the best AutoSuggest is the one from [brandspankingnew](http://www.brandspankingnew.net/archive/2006/08/ajax_auto-suggest_auto-complete.html)

Answer (score 1):

The autocomplete plugin has a timeout option you can set to do this.

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/AutoComplete/autocomplete