# jquery plugin - autocomplete

Tags: asp.net, jquery, autocomplete

please help me to choose the best plug-in in my particular scenario,

I am building a page where user enters first or last name initial and and I have around 25k records in my db.

what do you guys recommend?

Comment: Does this actually benefit the user? Isn't this a bit of a privacy concern?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Reading these other StackOverflow answers may help you!*

> - before start read this: [Efficient AutoSuggest with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2443362/efficient-autosuggest-with-jquery/2443532#2443532)
> - then go: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188442/whats-a-good-ajax-autocomplete-plugin-for-jquery
> - then go: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256105/what-is-the-best-jquery-autocomplete-suggest

Answer (score 2):

jquery ui [autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery UI has an autocomplete plugin that works really well.

[jQuery UI autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/)

Answer (score 0):

I just released an Asp.Net WebControl wrapping JQuery UI autocomplete widget.
You can find it on codeplex at the following address:

http://autocompletedotnet.codeplex.com/

Comment: You can find it here: http://autocompletedotnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you will like the original standalone jQuery autocompleter plugin that is still around (and actively developed):

http://code.google.com/p/jquery-autocomplete/